# how to Increase a counter every foreach complete loop in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a form that registers the values of five machines through a `foreach`.

followed by checking that the ending has the name of the text field and assigning it to the corresponding variable according to a comparison of patterns:

To save the value correctly I remove the `_1 _2 _3 _4 _5` for every key

**This is the function**

```
function registerMachines(){
    foreach($_POST as $item => $value){
        if(preg_match('/_1/', $item)){
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_1[$item] = $value;
        } elseif(preg_match('/_2/', $item)){
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_2[$item] = $value;
        } elseif(preg_match('/_3/', $item)){
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_3[$item] = $value;
        } elseif(preg_match('/_4/', $item)){
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_4[$item] = $value;
        } elseif(preg_match('/_5/', $item)){
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_5[$item] = $value;
        } else {
            $configData[$item] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want loop every value without assigning a data_number variable for every collection of data.

I get to this function:

```
$machines = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    foreach($_POST as $item => $value){
        foreach($machines as $machine) {
            $match = '/_'.$machine.'$/';
            if(preg_match($match, $item)){
                $item = explode("_", $item);
                $item = $item[0];
                ${"machineData_".$machine}[$item] = $value;
            } else {
                $configData[$item] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**How does it work?**

1. I go through all the values ​​of $ _POST.
2. I scan internally every machine ($ machine).
3. I create the pattern to check based on the value of the loop.
4. If it matches I eliminate the end of the $ item (_1, _2, _3, etc).
5. I create the variable (array) with the syntax $ {var. $ Machine} and assign it the value.

**The problem:**

When I go through the 50 input of the machines, the 5 paths are repeated to generate variables, therefore in a `var_dump 250` values ​​come out.

**What I wish?**

I would like to be able to go through each POST value and for this, all the machines will be reviewed and its value assigned to the correct one (array generated with $ {var})

Comment: not sure what you are up to... `$number` refers to nothing here...

Comment: @Pierre Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: Your _How can I get this?_ should show an actual array or string or whatever.  There can only be one `1` key for example.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i added the var_dump

Comment: No, what do you WANT?

Comment: @AbraCadaver i update it

Comment: Keys must be unique, you can not have more than one key the same do `var_dump(["1"=>"a", "1"=>"b", "1"=>"c"]);` and you will see.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i will add some more, i have this question in spanish site, but i will move here

Comment: @grumpyCrouton: he updated his buggy code after my comment, that's why it seemed silly to you

Comment: Anytime you use a variable with a number or most times when you use a variable variable, like `${"machineData_".$machine}` you should use an array like `$machineData[$machine][]`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i update again.

Comment: Use arrays.  You can send arrays from a form using `[]` or `[bla]` or `[1]` or whatever: `<input name="machine[`]" ...> <input name="machine[2]" ...>` will give you `$_POST['machine'][1]` and `$_POST['machine'][2]` etc...  Much much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two foreach

```
      foreach ($numbers  as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($letters as $keylet => $valuelet) {
          $data[$value] = $valuelet;
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should loop every iterate of first array

```
foreach($numbers as $number){
     foreach($letters as $letter){
        $data[$number] = $letter;
     }
}
```